# How can I use two completely independent power sources to power a circuit and cell phone buzzer triggered by a transistor separately?

Tags: circuit-analysis

The attached circuit and description was originally from another website.

The circuit as it is keeps the buzzer off until the FSR reaches 26  kΩ (light force), then turns it on until it reaches 10 kΩ (heavy force) then turns it off again.

I'm trying to keep this as small as possible, so far have tried to power it with two 3.0v CR2025 batteries in series but after a few cycles of the (cell phone) buzzer the voltage in the circuit drops changing the values input to the comparator causing inconsistencies.

My question is:  How can I use two completely independent power sources to power the circuit and buzzer separately?

Transistor:  https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mpsa42-d.pdf

A quick demo is in this YouTube short.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/MElcl9LruXY

The full schematic is shown below.

[image: Buzzer circuit]

Thanks.

Source: Practical Machinist - "O/T - Electronic circuit help?", post by Fred Hern
https://www.practicalmachinist.com/forum/threads/o-t-electronic-circuit-help.417884/

Comment: do you want something like a relay or an optocouiler (or something different)

Comment: Jim Kailey - Hi, Can you please [edit] the question to explain more details about *why* you need to power the buzzer from a "completely independent" power source and what its power source will be? || For example, if the buzzer will be (for example) 5 km from the main circuit and that's why it will be powered from a completely independent power source, that would lead to different possible answers than if the buzzer will be physically next to the circuit, but the buzzer is unusual and must be powered by (for example) 90 VAC. See what I mean? More context = more likely to get answers. Thanks.

Comment: How's that?????

Comment: @JimKailey - Thanks for trying. (a) Tbh that raises more questions e.g. why not power the whole device (circuit & buzzer) from whatever the buzzer's power source will be (along with any necessary regulation), since the buzzer will need its own power source. (b) You've now called the buzzer, a "cell phone" buzzer. In my experience, cell phones don't have *buzzers*. The closest thing I know is a (power hungry!) haptic vibration motor. If that's what you have, then perhaps this is an XY problem and all you need is a lower-power sounding device as a "buzzer"? I'll stop here, but sincere good luck.

Comment: I guess "vibrating motor" would be correct, they're used to create the vibration in cell phones apparently:  https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B087NQMYSS?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details  As it is now both the vibrating motor and the circuit are powered by a pair of CR2032 batteries in series but as mentioned they don't have the capacity and the voltage in the circuit drops.  I was thinking if the circuit had it's own set of batteries the voltage would remain stable.

Comment: Even without the "buzzer" this circuit needs too much current to be operated from coin cells. A solution with a microcontroller, that periodically turns on the measurement and sleeps in between, would give you a much longer usable period with coin cells as supply.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  How much current could the circuit alone draw?  CR2032 cells are rated at 220mAh, the buzzer only comes on intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of 3.7v LIR2032's and they seem to hold up so I'll close this, thanks for the replies.